# Using the C# Volatile keyword in Threaded Application

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, .net-3.5, volatile

I have a class that has a few arraylists in it.

My main class creates a new instance of this class. My main class has at least 2 threads adding and removing from my class with the arraylists in it.  At the moment everything is running fine but I was just wondering if it would be safer to declare my class with the arraylists in it as volatile eg/

```
private volatile myclass;
myclass = new myclass();
......
myclass.Add(...)
myclass.Clear(..)
```

Comment: volatile is applicable to fields only

Comment: Why do you want to make that volatile? Is it going to add any value to your application?

Comment: Now answer you question yourself and accept it. Almost 90% of your questions are answered by you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the volatile keyword will not make your code thread-safe in this example. The volatile keyword is typically used to ensure that when reading or writing the value of a variable (i.e. class field) that the latest value for that variable is either read from main memory or written straight to main memory, rather than read from cache (e.g. a CPU register) for example. The volatile keyword is a way of saying "do not use caching optimizations with this shared field", and removes the issue where threads may use local copies of a field and so not see each other's updates.

In your case the value of myclass is not actually being updated (i.e. you are not re-assigning myclass) so volatile is not useful for you, and it is not the update of the myclass variable you actually want to make thread-safe in this case anyway.

If you wish to make updating of the actual class thread-safe, then using a "lock" around "Add" and "Clear" is a straight-forward alternative. This will ensure that only one thread at a time can do these operations (which update the internal state of myclass) and so should not be done in parallel.

A lock can be used as follows:

```
private readonly object syncObj = new object(); 
private readonly myclass = new myclass();
......

lock (syncObj)
{
    myclass.Add(...)
}

lock (syncObj)
{
    myclass.Clear(..)
}
```

You also need to add locking around any code that reads the state that is being updated by "Add", if that is the case although it does not appear in your example code.

It may not be obvious when first writing multi-threaded code why you would need a lock when adding to a collection. If we take List or ArrayList as an example, then the problem arises as internally these collections use an Array as a backing store, and will dynamically "grow" this Array (i.e. by creating a new larger Array and copying the old contents) as certain capacities are met when Add is called. This all happens internally and requires the maintenance of this Array and variables such as what current size the collection is (rather than the Length of the actual array which might be larger). So Adding to the collection may involve multiple steps if the internal Array needs to grow. When using multiple threads in an unsafe manner, multiple threads may indirectly cause growing to happen when Adding, and thus trample all over each others updates. As well as the issue of multiple threads Adding at the same time, there is also the issue that another thread may be trying to read the collection *whilst* the internal state is being changed. Using locks ensures that operations like these are done without interference from other threads.

Comment: Is it better to put a lock around a object like you say or lock(this).  What happens when a lock is used and another thread tries to access it. Does it just sit their waiting?

Comment: @Jon **Question** 1: It is best to lock on a private lock variable rather than "this", as "this" is also visible to anyone that has a reference to that class instance i.e. threads from outside the class could lock on a reference to the class which is in effect the same thing. This is an unintended consequence of using "this".

Comment: @Jon **Question** 2: When a thread attempts to enter a lock section that is busy (this is called lock contention) in effect that thread is suspended, and then woken up when the lock becomes free. If there are multiple threads waiting, only one thread will succeed and the rest will be suspended again. Actual lock checking and taking is very very quick when locks are not contended i.e. busy. Try and keep code within locks efficient, but when multi-threading, correctness and readability are very important. Get correctness and unit tests in place before trying to optimize the hell out of things.

Answer (score 2):

At present, the code is wrong; adding a `volatile` keyword won't fix it. It's not safe to use the .NET classes across threads without adding synchronisation.

It's hard to give straightforward advice without knowing more about the structure of your code. A first step would be to start using the `lock` keyword around all accesses to the list object; however, there could still be assumptions in the code that don't work across multiple threads.

It's possible to use a collection class that's already safe for multithreaded access, which would avoid the need for getting the `lock` keyword in the right place, but it's still possible to make errors.

Can you post some more of your code? That way we can give more specific suggestions about making it thread safe.

Comment: This page provides a good explanation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/573ths2x(VS.90).aspx. But using a thread-safe collection on its own probably won't fix the problem; if your code is anything like mine, it's going to be doing things with the items themselves in an unsafe way.

Comment: Thanks. Essentially my class has a few arraylists and then I have created Add/Delete/Clear/Find commands in my class which goes off to the relevant arraylist and does its thing. However this instance of my class may call Add/Remove on up to 2 threads. It sounds like I need to lock this instance of my class whenever it is being used.